# Each iterator not outputting value of content array

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I've got an arrayController that contains a list of recent search terms. When I push an item to the array it correctly displays the quantity of items on the view except for one problem...I can't get the name to print.

Here's the pertinent code

```
App.recentUsersArray = Em.ArrayController.create({
    content: [],
    addUser: function(name) {
        this.pushObject(name);
    }
});

<ol>
    {{#each App.recentUsersArray}}
        <li>
            {{#view App.RecentNameView}} {{name}} {{/view}}
            {{#view App.RecentNameDeleteView}}X{{/view}}
        </li>
    {{/each}}
</ol>
```

Inside this line: `{{#view App.RecentNameView}} {{/view}}` I've tried `{{name}}`. `{{content.name}}` but neither work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using "this":  http://jsfiddle.net/s7DbE/

Or this, which is answers the question a little better: http://jsfiddle.net/s7DbE/1/

Or this fiddle, which reverses the inputs: http://jsfiddle.net/s7DbE/2/

Comment: {{this}} inside the RecentNameView merely prints out the object string.

Comment: Great. Thank you Fadi! Worked perfectly with the contentBinding.